Why can't I LoadUserProfile for another user as non-admin?
I created a separate account on my PC (no domain controller), and want to read its environment block.
To do that I first obtain a token using
LogonUser(logon, domain, password,
          LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
          LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
          out var userToken);

This succeeds.
Then I try
profile = new PROFILEINFOW {
    dwSize = SizeOf<PROFILEINFOW>(),
    lpUserName = ...,
    lpDefaultPath = null,
    lpServerName = null,
    dwFlags = 0,
};
LoadUserProfile(userToken, ref profile);

Now this fails with "A required privilege is not held by the client" (error 1314) unless my own process is elevated. But why? I already got user token and can run anything as that user.

The calling process must have the SE_RESTORE_NAME and SE_BACKUP_NAME privileges enabled in token. and probably you not enable it

Note the privilege is needed in the access token of the calling process, not in the user token that is being loaded. "The calling process must have the SE_RESTORE_NAME and SE_BACKUP_NAME privileges. For more information, see Running with Special Privileges." And in particular Changing Privileges in a Token. Use OpenProcessToken() to get the process token that you can then adjust before loading the profile.
